# Convert an Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] to a DenseMatrix[Double] in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-breeze

I have this solution which works but I wonder if there's a clever way to do it, avoiding the explicit for loop and the `toString.toDouble` conversion

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

val rows: Array[Row] = df2.collect()
//rows: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([-1.35980713367,...

var e = ArrayBuffer[Array[Double]]()

for(row <- rows){
  val x = row.toSeq.toArray
  val y = x.map(_.toString.toDouble)
  e += y
}
val dm = DenseMatrix(e.toArray:_*)
```

Comment: you can use denseMatrix in dataframe itself using udf function. did you try that? if you include some sample input and expected output then we can show you how.

Comment: `rows.map(_.getAs[Double](0)`?

Comment: I'm beginning with spark so I'm not very familiar with udf functions but I'll investigate that approach.